# Controlling the direction of curve extrusion

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Is there an easy way to control how the extruded width of a curve object is oriented, for example like this
[image]

or this
[image]

The curve in the images above has only two control points, and I got the effect by rotating one of the points. However, for a curve with lots of control points it would be somewhat difficult or at least tedious to achieve this. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Consider changing the **Tilt**, In *Edit Mode* of the curve, <kbd>N</kbd> for properties, you will see a tilt angle which you can change:

  [image]
- Consider a lattice modifier.  Animate the strength of the modifier if that suits you
- Consider a simple deform modifier

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is called *Tilt*. You can control the tilt of a given segment with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think both answers are equally good, and I chose the other one simply because you already have enough rep... ;-)